# How to clone node in Angular UI tree?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-tree

How to clone node in Angular UI tree with all children?

Now I use event click: `ng-click="newSubItem(this)"` where `newSubItem` is function:

```
$scope.newSubItem = function (scope) {

                var nodeData = scope.$modelValue;
                var arrr_nodes = [];

                angular.forEach(nodeData.nodes, function (value) {
                    arrr_nodes.push(arrr_nodes);
                });

                var total_nodes = nodeData.nodes.length;
                var prefix_increment = total_nodes + 1;

                nodeData.nodes.push({
                    id: nodeData.id + prefix_increment,
                    prefix: nodeData.prefix + "_" + prefix_increment,
                    title: nodeData.title + '.' + (nodeData.nodes.length + 1),
                    value: nodeData.value,
                    type: nodeData.type,
                    nodes: arrr_nodes
                });
            };
```

When I try to insert all children from cloned object to new `nodes: nodes: arrr_nodes` it gives a lot of errors and breaks tree.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Comment: Can you explain me, why input field in example is working, but by me is not?

Comment: Angular.copy makes a deep clone of the object, it looks like your code is just copying in references to the original arr_nodes.

Comment: Can you share an example please

Comment: ok,  see below...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do inside that `newSubItem` function -- it doesn't return anything, so it's not obvious what the purpose is.

But you're not cloning objects, instead you're

- copying object references (`nodeData` is just a reference to `scope.$modelValue`, so if the modelValue changes later on so will `nodeData`) and
- creating circular data structures (by pushing the array onto itself, `arrr_nodes.push(arrr_nodes);`),

neither of which is  probably what you want.

To answer your stated question, if you're trying to make a deep clone of an object, Angular provides `angular.copy()` which does exactly that.  If your intent is for `nodeData` to be a clone of the `modelValue`, all you need is

```
$scope.newSubItem = function (scope) {
    var nodeData = angular.copy(scope.$modelValue);
    // presumably now you would do something useful with nodeData
}
```